# Getting a Key Error 'gs' when trying to write a dask dataframe to csv on google cloud storage

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-cloud-storage, dask

I have the following code below where I'm 1) importing a csv file from a gcs bucket 2) doing some etl on it and 3) converting it to dask df before writing the dask df to_csv.  All goes to plan until the very end when I get a `KeyError: 'gs'` upon writing to csv back in a gcs bucket.

here is my code - can anyone help me understand where the key error comes from?

```
def stage1_1ph_prod_master(data, context):  

    from google.cloud import storage
    import pandas as pd
    import dask.dataframe as dd
    import io
    import numpy as np
    import datetime as dt


    source_bucket = 'sourcebucket'
    destination_path = 'gs://destination_bucket/ddf-*ph_master_static.csv'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    source_bucket = storage_client.bucket(source_bucket)

    # load in the col names
    col_names = ["PPG_Code","PPG_Code_Name","SAP_Product_Name","CP_Sku_Code","UPC_Unit","UPC_Case","Category","Product_Category","Sub_Category","Brand","Sub_Brand","Variant","Size","Gender","Last_Updated_By","Last_Updated_On","Created_By","Created_On","Gross_Weight_Case_kg","Case_Height_mm",]

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

    for file in list(source_bucket.list_blobs()):
        file_path="gs://{}/{}".format(file.bucket.name, file.name)
        df = df.append(pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, skiprows=28, names=col_names, encoding='Latin_1'))


    ddf0 = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1, sort=True)
    ddf0.to_csv(destination_path) # Key Error happens here
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 383, in run_background_function _function_handler.invoke_user_function(event_object) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 217, in invoke_user_function return call_user_function(request_or_event) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 214, in call_user_function event_context.Context(**request_or_event.context)) File "/user_code/main.py", line 43, in stage1_1ph_prod_master ddf0.to_csv(destination_path) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1299, in to_csv return to_csv(self, filename, **kwargs) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/csv.py", line 741, in to_csv **(storage_options or {}) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 302, in open_files urlpath, mode, num=num, name_function=name_function, storage_options=kwargs File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 425, in get_fs_token_paths fs, fs_token = get_fs(protocol, options) File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/bytes/core.py", line 571, in get_fs cls = _filesystems[protocol] KeyError: 'gs'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcsfs and dask has recently changed to use the fsspec package. The former has been released, but the latter is in master only. So gcsfs is no longer registering itself with the filesystems in dask, because fsspec already knows about it, but the version of dask you are using does not yet know about fsspec.

In short, please downgrade gcsfs until we have a chance to release dask, or use dask from master.